# Sencha Touch chart - How to add percentage as left axis

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-charts

I am using Sencha Touch charts 1.0.0. From the docs, there is only type='Numeric', no 'percentage' type.

How can I add percentages to left axis? I tried giving the data as percentages ('20%', .. etc) but it didnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your axis  just add  this,

```
{
 type: 'Numeric',
 fields: ['Data'],
  position: 'left',
label: {
         renderer: function(v) {
            return ((v * 100).toFixed(0)).concat('%');
                          }
                    }

 }
```